# Help with infinitive construction

Tags: sentence-structure, accusative-and-infinitive

> *Hoffentlich werde ich euch sehen, eine neue Fremdsprache lernen.*

I want to say, “Hopefully I will see you guys learning a new language.”

Does this even make sense, or do I need to add a *zu* into the last part? I know the sentence sounds really off …

Comment: Yes, this sentence is definitely a mile off, it sounds like English literally translated into German. Infinitive constructions in German *always* use *zu* (unless the finite verb is a strong modal verb), but even if you add the *zu*, the sentence still sounds English. And speaking of off, this may well be off-topic, too; as it may be understood as a proofreading request (see the [help/on-topic])

Comment: „Hoffentlich werde ich euch eine neue Fremdsprache lernen sehen.“ I'm going to bed now, therefore I do not write a full answer.

Comment: @Jan: Never say never, always qualify always. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few verbs, among them in particular verbs of perception like *sehen*, can use a special construction called [*accusative and infinitive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_and_infinitive). In that construction, the plain infinitive without *zu* is used, and the person being seen doing something is put in accusative.

So your sentence isn’t far off, there is only a small word order issue: The second part of the main verb (if any) goes at the end of the sentence, after the accusative and infinitive:

> Hoffentlich werde ich euch *(acc.)* eine neue Fremdsprache lernen *(inf.)* sehen.
>   Hoffentlich sehe ich euch *(acc.)* eine neue Fremdsprache lernen *(inf.)*.

Commas can’t be used here.

Instead of an accusative and infinitive construction, a subordinate clause can always be used:

> Hoffentlich werde ich sehen, wie ihr eine neue Fremdsprache lernt.